# How can I add a vertical social share bar in my shiny R app?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to add a vertical floating social bar in my shiny R app. I got the HTML code from [sharebutton.net](http://sharebutton.net), here it is:

```
<script>
document.write('<script src="//sharebutton.net/plugin/sharebutton.php? type=vertical&u=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href) + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

And this is my code:

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)

ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("title panel"),
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel("Panel 1"),
tabPanel("Panel 2")),
tags$script(HTML("<script>
               document.write('<script src=\"//sharebutton.net/plugin/sharebutton.php?type=vertical&u=' 
               + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href) + '\"></scr' + 'ipt>');"))))
server <- function(input, output){}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I get no errors, however no social bar either. Also, how can I add a text and my webpage in this social bar? The final result should be something like that [PERMUTATION TEST](http://rosetta.ahmedmoustafa.io/permutation)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you figure out the answer?